# Glossaries - Acronyms in ignored glossary with short-long style

Tags: glossaries

I've noticed that the `glossaries` package with an acronym in an ignored glossary does not print the long form on first use if the acronym style `short-long` is used. With `long-short`, it works as expected.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newignoredglossary{common}

\makeglossaries

\setacronymstyle{short-long}

\newacronym{sample}{SAMPLE}{Some Long Form}

\newacronym[type=common]{commonex}{COMMON}{Another Long Form}

\begin{document}

First Use: \gls{sample} -- \gls{commonex}.

Second Use: \gls{sample} -- \gls{commonex}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: sample-ignored]

I've tested this with glossaries v4.21 & v4.40. Both show that behavior.
Is this intended and I'm doing it wrong or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify the ignored glossary as an acronym list using the `acronymlists` package option or `\DeclareAcronymList` (described in section 2.5 of the `glossaries` user manual):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronymlists={main,common}]{glossaries}

\newignoredglossary{common}

\makeglossaries

\setacronymstyle{short-long}

\newacronym{sample}{SAMPLE}{Some Long Form}

\newacronym[type=common]{commonex}{COMMON}{Another Long Form}

\begin{document}

First Use: \gls{sample} -- \gls{commonex}.

Second Use: \gls{sample} -- \gls{commonex}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image: First Use: SAMPLE (Some Long Form) – COMMON (Another Long Form). Second Use: SAMPLE – COMMON. Glossary SAMPLE Some Long Form. 1]